# Back to previous page after login in php

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to modify the loginController and AuthenticatesUsers files so that there are two options once you log in:

if you log in through the normal form that takes you to the predefined page as "home" and if you log in through the forms that force you to log in to perform an action this will take you back to that page.

How could this be done? I've seen a lot of related questions, but none of them try two options.

I modified the redirectPath variable and tried to overwrite some methods, but I don't know how to make the two options coexist.

Comment: Please show us some example code.

Comment: You can create a variable that will tell you the type of the login option and based on that option you can redirect.

Comment: you can give like this `return redirect()->intended('home');` for more information about intended method read document here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function in LoginController instead of redirectTo variable:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if () {
        return 'previous url';
    }

        return 'home';
}
```